# Получение md5-хэша строки

Tags: c++-cli

Как превратить `String^ a;` в md5 хэш? c++ / cli.

Заранее спасибо. На msdn не нашел нормального примера =(

Answer (score 1):

Подсчет контрольной суммы MD5 производится вызовом метода [`MD5CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s02tk69a.aspx). Пример:

```
StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder();

using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create()) {
    byte[] data = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source));

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
        hash.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
}
```

Это C#. На C++/CLI аналогично.